# GPO not removing from client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have a windows 2012 server. And I have applied a setting using scheduler that, it will run an `.exe` file every one hour. After that, I have removed the policy from server. But the `.exe` file is still running in the client machine which I don't want. I have tried `gpupdate /force` but doesn't work.

I have tried `gpresult /h report.html` at the client machine. It displays a result that the .exe related policy is not there.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

That's how group policy works, please read the documentation <strike>again</strike>.  If you want to remove the scheduled task from the client then you can do this by removing the scheduled task on the client manually.  Removing the GPO or group policy preference item within the GPO does not remove the task.  You may alter this behaviour using the group policy setting 'Remove this item when it is no longer applied'.

Comment: i cannot see anything in schedule task in client machine. actually, everyone hour a .exe file will run from server shared folder using task scheduler. i removed the policy from the server. but still the exe is running in client machine.